# What's happening in this javascript function?

Tags: javascript

First, what condition is `document.body` being checked against?  Is it whether or not a body tag is present?  Second, what's happening to the `eval()` parameters?  I'm pretty sure values from the lists are being passed into `setBodyAttr` to ultimately produce, for example, `document.body.text="deepblue";` (which seems to be deprecated syntax), but how is that happening?

If you notice down by the lists attributes are being passed such as `setBodyAttr('text', value)` with `''` around `text`.  That is then concatenated in `eval()` with another `''`.  Values, on the other hand, are not passed with `''` but are concatenated with `''` inside `""`.  What exactly is `eval()` doing to take all that and produce `document.body.text="darkblue";`, for example?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DOM Tests</title>
    <script type="application/javascript">
    function setBodyAttr(attr,value){
      if (document.body) eval('document.body.'+attr+'="'+value+'"');
      else notSupported();
    }
    </script>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div style="margin: .5in; height: 400;"> 
      <p><b><tt>text</tt>color</b></p> 
      <form> 
        <select onChange="setBodyAttr('text',
        this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"> 
          <option value="black">black 
          <option value="darkblue">darkblue 
        </select>
        <p><b><tt>bgColor</tt></b></p>
        <select onChange="setBodyAttr('bgColor',
        this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"> 
          <option value="white">white 
          <option value="lightgrey">gray
        </select>
        <p><b><tt>link</tt></b></p> 
        <select onChange="setBodyAttr('link',
        this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
          <option value="blue">blue
          <option value="green">green
        </select>  <small>
        <a href="http://www.brownhen.com/dom_api_top.html" id="sample">
        (sample link)</a></small><br>
      </form>
      <form>
        <input type="button" value="version" onclick="ver()" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if(document.body)` - if the browser DOM returns *any* truth-y value; see [document.body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body). The eval is some terribly hackish stuff and should be written as `document.body[attr] = value`, if at all.

Comment: @user2864740 — "returns any value", no, it has to be a true value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First, what condition is document.body being checked against: whether or not a body tag is present?

Just about. It is checking for the existence of the body element. (You can have a body element without a body tag since the stand and end tags for it are optional).

> Second, what's happening to the eval() parameters? I'm pretty sure values from the lists are being passed into setBodyAttr to ultimately produce, for example, document.body.text="deepblue"; (which seems to be deprecated syntax), but how is it happening?

`eval` takes a string and executes it as JS.

So that generates the string `document.body.text="deepblue";` and executes it as if it were  a JS statement.

The syntax isn't deprecated, it is just very bad practise.

The sensible approach would be:

```
document.body[attr] = value;
```

Comment: What happens to the '' initial passed with TEXT, and the '' concatenated to it?  Same with the value parameter.  Basically I'm just confused how all those '' turn into the final string to be executed.

Comment: '' *initially passed

Comment: @user5948022 — In that particular example `'` are used to delimit the string literals that make up (along with the `attr` variable) the JS code to be evaluated and the `"` delimit the string literal that is part of that code.

Comment: could you tell me why this is needed?

Comment: Basically I don't know what delimiting is.  I'll look it up myself, just wanted to get a general idea while I'm here.